# SDL Window Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I have a `Storage` class which is basically my application and which helds and manipulates its data.

In a seperate thread, I want a SDL Window which constantly (every few milliseconds) draws some data of `Storage` object onto the screen. The window should allow interaction (like zooming) but does **not** modify the data in the `Storage` object, it just reads them!

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    Storage storage;        // The object which holds the data to be displayed in the following window

    GridWindow *grid = new GridWindow (&storage);
    std::thread t(&GridWindow ::init, grid);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));  // wait a bit to see if the window reacts to the new data

    // put some data into memory
    storage.RandomDataGeneration();

    // prevent the main function from exiting
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

My GridWindow.cpp:

```
#include "GridWindow.h"
#include <thread>

GridWindow::GridWindow(Storage* storage)
    : storage(storage)
{       
}

GridWindow::~GridWindow(){
    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void GridWindow::init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2        
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        window_width,                      // width, in pixels
        window_height,                     // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
        );

    drawGrid();
    return;
}

void GridWindow::drawGrid()
{
    while (true){
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            // handle your event here
        }           

            SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    // Set Background Color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    // Clear window
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            // draw some rectangles in the Color provided in the storage object
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        SDL_Rect r;
        r.x = i*10
        r.y = 1;
        r.w = 10;
        r.h = 10;

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, storage.rcolor, storage.gcolor, storage.bcolor, 255);

        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    }

    // Render the rect to the screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(80);

    }
    return;
}
```

The window is shown and does the drawing, but it Shows the data from before the `RandomDataGeneration()` call. Where is the Problem?

Comment: I think this line : `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` pause the current thread, not the GUI thread. You should move it in the init method of GridWindow.

Comment: Hi, yes this was actually intended. For example: I wanted to see if the window reacts to changes of the storage data inside the main thread. Hope you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: I see your point. But to me it seems that you create Storage, then you create the GridWindow. Then move the window to another thread, so it live on its own. Then you wait one seconds on the main thread (the window will get update during this second). Then you generate your data in storage.
Try printing data in console in your drawing loop to check if it can access the data.

Comment: Hmm ok I tried accessing the data within the draw Loop: it correctly reads the updated value. So somehow it doesn't redraw the window correctly.

Comment: If you add some drawing code perhaps we can help you.

Comment: I added some simplified code. Thanks a lot!